# Autologin multiple Skype instances

Tags: skype

I have found that it is possible to run multiple instances of Skype using the /secondary key.

The second instance, however, asks to enter or select credentials, while I want it just to pick the  username which have not been used by the first instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I have found and use is combining the `/secondary` key with the `/username:` key:

```
start /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone" Skype.exe /username:user1 /secondary
start /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone" Skype.exe /username:user2 /secondary
```

This requres pressing a button `Sign me in` in the second instance's welcome window. This fills in the passord automatically, however.

Comment: If you are lazy about pressing sign in button everytime, you can add argument `/password:xyz` to it. It will then auto sign-in

Comment: Given [DatLicht's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/327928/autologin-multiple-skype-instances/1112814#1112814), it seems these command line parameters have been removed last year. (I have not tested that.)

Comment: /password not working anymore 2017

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago, there were switches /username and /password when starting with a secondary Skype account.

Now, these switches are disabled, also see here: https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/Secondary-Skype-stopped-working/m-p/4221641/highlight/true#M307935

Unfortunately, Skype remembers the last used account name in the file %programdata%\Skype\shared.xml, so you cannot directly specify what account to logon when Skype starts (if starting with /secondary switch, Skype always asks you for your credentials).

Also, it's not recommended to manipulate that file and auto-restore it every time you start skype because that XML file doesn't just contain your user name, it also contains a part of your Skype settings.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe check out this, auto login to two accounts: http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/How-to-run-multiple-Skype-Logons-with-different-icons/td-p/1705798

Comment: Could you add a summary of the link? Something along the lines of: It involves making 2 new shortcuts for your 2 accounts and making a script to make sure it works...